# Should we write $y=mx+c$ as $c + mx$?

Tags: geometry, convention

This may seem like a really pointless question but bear in mind I am thinking from the perspective of a school maths teacher.

I am recently thinking it would be more intuitive to have a convention of writing the straight line equation in the form $y = c + mx$ rather than $y = mx + c$.

This is because it more clearly describes the fact that you have something growing outwards by m per 1 x, while adding that we know *where* it is growing from.

y = c + mx suggests start at point c, and then to get to anywhere on the line, add some multiple (x) of m...

This feels more like what a straight line is.

Any opinions on this convention? Or wider intuition on how to think of a straight line equation?

Comment: Addition is commutative. It doesn't matter.

Comment: I think it's six of one, half dozen of the other.  Writing $y=mx+b$ gives priority to the truly linear function $y=mx$...the new function is then a simple translate of that.  But there's nothing wrong with writing it your way either.

Comment: Personally, I see no objection.

Comment: $mx+b\Leftrightarrow b+mx$, the terms are equivalent.

Comment: would you also advocate $y=a+bx+cx^2$ for a quadratic?

Comment: .me to ok seems ?order the about cares who

Comment: There is law called commutative so This is it which is said a+b=b+a

Comment: It doesn’t matter that much either way imo. But one way of introducing y=mx+c is to do a 2-by-k table (with k x-values), finding the values of y fir given values if x, and plotting these points ( x,y) on an empty graph and drawing a straight line through the points. If you introduce straight lines on graphs this way, it should be clear that y=3x+6 the same line as y=6+3x, so from this perspective it doesn’t matter

Comment: I prefer this.  When writing a polynomial sequence, it's better to write the terms ordered by their powers.  This coincides with writing the change-of-basis matrix:

$1$,
$1 + 2x$,
$3 + 2x + 4x^2$,
$\ldots$

so that the first column is all the coefficients of $x^0$, the second column is all the coefficient of $x^1$, and so on.

Comment: "would you also advocate $y=a+bx+cx^2$ for a quadratic?"  Why not?  And why not $y = a+cx^2 + bx$ or $y=ax + b + cx^2$?  Does it matter?

Comment: Actually if I think intuitively of where the line is "growing from" is from the $x$ intercept and thus the most intuitive way should be.... $y = m(x-k)$ and ...wait, that's not intuitive at all.... or is it?... actually it *is*!.... or is it not? .....

Answer (score 2):

> This is because it more clearly describes the fact that you have something growing outwards by m per 1 x, while adding that we know where it is growing from.

This is not wrong and you have a point.

But why do we *care* what it's growing from? Isn't the rate of growth more important than where the line began, which is just an offset?

In the end it doesn't matter.  After all addition is commutative and it is actually *bad* practice in math to associate emphasis of an equation on where something occurs.  But more importantly the argument as to how important the initial value is, versus the heavy mechanics and shifting an moving, is subjective.

And I dare say I disagree and think the heavy mechanics and shifting is more important.  I certainly think if I had a polynomial, I'd want it written as $a_nx^n + .... + a_1 x + a_0$ rather than $a_0 + a_1x + .... +a_nx^n$ *because* the $a_nx^n$ is more "influential" than the $a_0$.  And I'd say the $mx$ is more influential then that $c$.

But 1) it doesn't really matter and 2) It's pretty subjective.

Comment: Yes, I like that last part: the leading term ought to come first, else our terminology is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

While both notations are equivalent due to the commutative property of addition, it seems like the equation is written as $y = mx + c$ because this is the canonical polynomial form with respect to $x$. For example, you could write it as $y = mx^1 + cx^0$. If it were a quadratic equation, it would be written as $y = m_1x^2+m_2x+c$.

Comment: Not sure on exact correct terms, as I've been out of the math world for a while, so feel free to edit for clarity.

Comment: I think it's only barely canonical. $y=c+bx+ax^2$ is slightly odd but not completely rare.

Comment: @Jam It would be better if we did use that form since it would be consistent with Taylor series.

Comment: @OscarCunningham I'm not convinced. We are usually interested in highest-degree terms for polynomials (since they dominate) but for power series, we're usually interested in lowest-degree terms (since highest terms disappear).

Answer (score 0):

It is the same function, order is immaterial even if we write

$$ y= c+ mx $$

which gives initial intercept $c$ and slope $m.$

By the same token a parabola of focal length $f$ can be expressed

$$ y= c+ mx + \frac{x^2}{4f}$$

that has constants $(c,m,f)$ relates as initial intercept, initial slope and initial radius of curvature.